MAUI: Collectionview content is not visible when adding a RefreshView
I have added a RefreshView for a CollectionView. After adding RefreshView, the CollectionView contents are not visible on the UI. The CollectionView contents are visible on the UI before adding RefreshView. Below is the code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    BackgroundColor="White"
    x:Class="NeedHelp.Pages.FriendDetailsPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid BackgroundColor="#eeeeee">
                
            </Grid>

            <ScrollView 
                x:Name="frienddetails_scrollview"
                IsVisible="False"
                Orientation="Vertical" 
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                
                <StackLayout
                    Margin="15">
                    
                    <Frame 
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        Padding="5">
                        
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        Padding="3"
                        x:Name="map_layout"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        
                    </Frame>

                    <Label
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        x:Name="History_label"
                        Text="History"
                        TextColor="#424242"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                    </Label>

                    <Frame
                        x:Name="Tab_layout"
                        BorderColor="#efefef"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Padding="5">

                    </Frame>

                    <ListView 
                        x:Name="historylistview"
                        SeparatorVisibility="None"
                        HasUnevenRows="True"
                        SelectionMode="None"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        BackgroundColor="#ffffff">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <ViewCell.View>
                                        <StackLayout
                                            Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                            
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell.View>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        <ListView.Footer>
                            <Label/>
                        </ListView.Footer>
                    </ListView>
                    
                <RefreshView 
                    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                    Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

                    <CollectionView 
                        x:Name="MyTweetsList" 
                        Margin="0,5,0,5"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems,Mode=TwoWay}"
                        RemainingItemsThreshold="0"
                        RemainingItemsThresholdReached="LoadMoreTweets"
                        HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout
                                    x:Name="Item"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    Orientation="Vertical">

                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                <OnIdiom.Phone>400</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                <OnIdiom.Tablet>600</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                <OnIdiom.Desktop>400</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                            </OnIdiom>
                        </CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                    </CollectionView>
                </RefreshView>

                    <Label
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        IsVisible="{Binding ComingSoonVisibility}"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Text="No Messages Yet."
                        x:Name="no_announcement_label"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            
            <Grid 
                x:Name="tweetBox"
                IsVisible="False"
                Margin="0,0,0,10">

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

public ICommand RefreshCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;
            
            LoadData();
            
            IsRefreshing = false;
        });
    }
}


private bool _isRefreshing = false;
public bool IsRefreshing
{
    get { return _isRefreshing; }
    set
    {
        _isRefreshing = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRefreshing));
    }
}

Do I need to add anything else to view the data on UI when adding RefreshView?

Have you rechecked that the data is loaded correctly by method LoadData();?

@JessieZhang-MSFT The issue is not when refreshing. When loading for the initial time the collectionview data is not visible on the UI.

And could you please post the whole code of .xaml of current page?

@JessieZhang-MSFT  I have updated the question with the entire UI structure, could you please check now.

@JessieZhang-MSFT I tried the same on a fresh demo project and over there it is working fine. But only on my main project it is not working, so it must be the issue with my existing layout structure.

The issue is related to ScrollView presence. Remove it and then collection view content will be visible. Consider it as a bug in .Net Maui.

It is not advisable to put collection view or listview inside scrollview. Moreover refresh view is next layer to interact with. Putting everything in single container makes troubles.

Yes, it is just the case as you said.
But as a workaround, you can add a StackLayout outside of RefreshView and set a special value for property HeightRequest.
You can refer to the following code:
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="YellowGreen" HeightRequest="200" VerticalOptions="Fill" > 

                    <RefreshView  BackgroundColor="Pink"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">

                        <CollectionView
                        BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                    x:Name="MyTweetsList"
                    Margin="0,5,0,5"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout
                                x:Name="Item"
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" />


                                    </StackLayout>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>400</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>600</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>400</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </RefreshView>

                </StackLayout>

Note:
1.And there is a known issue about this: CollectionView in RefreshView is not showing in VerticalStackLayout but is showing in StackLayout,so please use StackLayout not VerticalStackLayout.
2.Please remember to set property IsVisible of outer ScrollView to true,  otherwise you won't see any of the views in it.
      <ScrollView 
            x:Name="frienddetails_scrollview"
            IsVisible="False"
      </ScrollView>


But I don't have any verticalstacklayout in my code

Hi @MatthewPans, thanks for your feedback.  Because there are currently related issues in this regard, I just made a kind reminder in the note.  :)

Thank you @JessieZhang-MSFT the note about the VerticalStackLayout helped me
